# How to grab the Title field instead of the url

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a menu that grabs the path of the url in sitecore and matches it to the actual url. IE:

Home/Main/Folder/this-is-the-title = www.website.com/this-is-the-title

What I am trying to do is use the "Title" field in Sitecore to display the title on the page instead of the path property.

HTML

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="leftNavImage">
       <li>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="innerHyperLink" runat="server" ></asp:HyperLink>
       </li>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

C#

```
if (innerItem != null)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // this creates a link to the page in sitecore once clicked
        HyperLink topNavigation = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("innerHyperLink");
        topNavigation.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(innerItem);
        topNavigation.Text = innerItem.Name;
    }
}
```

I tried adding  to the front end inbetween the Hyperlink, but all it did was take the title and replicate with all the links instead of page link. Also I tried to set a variable in the backend to represent the Title but it was not cooperating, var title = Sitecore.Context.Item["Title"].ToString; . I'm sure it is a simple answer but I seem to be missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (innerItem != null)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            // this creates a link to the page in sitecore once clicked
            HyperLink topNavigation = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("innerHyperLink");
            topNavigation.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(innerItem);
            topNavigation.Text = innerItem["Title"];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use an `sc:Text` or `sc:FieldRenderer` control and set the Item in your repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="leftNavImage">
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="innerHyperLink" runat="server" >
                <sc:Text Field="Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If you want to completely get rid of the code behind code you could replace the `asp:HyperLink` with:

```
<a href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item) Container.DataItem) %>">
    <sc:Text Field="Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
</a>
```